# How to PAN and ZOOM NSImages for a Cocoa MAC OS application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, pan, zooming

As the title says, I want to be able to PAN images (NSImages) with a mouse cursor, and ZOOM images in any way. How can I do that as I can't find any resources online, someone please help!

Comment: WHY are you CAPITALIZING random WORDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at using [Apples's IKImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageView/IKImageView_Reference.html).

> The IKImageView class provides an efficient way to display images in a
>   view while at the same time supporting a number of image editing
>   operations such as rotating, zooming, and cropping. It supports drag
>   and drop, so that the user can drag an image to the view. If possible,
>   image rendering uses hardware acceleration to achieve optimal
>   performance. The IKImageView class is implemented as a subclass of
>   NSView. Similar to NSImageView, the IKImageView class is used to
>   display a single image.

IKImageView has some shortcomings, but in my experience zooming works well.

Comment: I'm dropping images into a window and want to translate and scale those images, do you know if those shortcomings have anything to do with that? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: I seem to remember those working well, but it has been a while since I used it. My suggestion is to give it a shot and see if it works for you. It is fairly easy to get it up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSAffineTransform` to translate and scale the coordinate system of the graphics context prior to drawing the image.  This would typically be within your `-drawRect:` method.